# iPhone device - connect to host computer

Tags: iphone, ios, networking, localhost

I'm developing an iPhone app that connects to a server. For now, the server is running locally. In the iPhone simulator, I can connect to `localhost` and test it that way. However, this doesn't work running it on an actual device, because then `localhost` is the device itself.

Is there an easy way for the device to connect to the server running on the host computer? Or do I have to resort to putting the server somewhere else?

Comment: connects to a server via http client?, in that case you need to use a reacheable ip (it can be your local ip assuming both devices are in the same network).

Comment: @rufo: well it's via my own protocol. I was hoping there was a way to do it without a reachable IP, say if apple was clever and supplied that functionality via the data cable somehow.

Comment: not a clue... I guess you have an strong reason for this - really looks out of the ordinary, and in any case in production you'll need to be able to connect to a reachable ip, otherwise it wouldn't work for your users. So I cannot imagine how something that doesn't work for you with your local ip will work at all to anybody else.

Comment: @rufo: the local IP thing worked actually, only saw that after i made my comment. but i had to do it by connecting to the same wifi network. so, if i had no wi-fi network, and my computer was behind a router and thus not reachable from the internet, would i have any recourse?

Comment: Correct - I see no option, you must have IP connectivity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than using `localhost`, replace that with your computer's IP address. That should work for both the simulator and device.